# How Can i Get Youtube Video Story Board from get_video_info URL in PHP Json

Tags: php, arrays, json, urldecode

How to i get Youtube video Storyboard Thumbnail with Signature from this URL
in PHP 
`http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=V1NW91yW6MA&asv=3&el=detailpage&hl=en_US`

I am trying this code

```
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=V1NW91yW6MA&asv=3&el=detailpage&hl=en_US';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
parse_str($data);
$array = explode('&', $storyboard_spec);

for ($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++){
    $array[$i] =urldecode($array[$i]);
}
$json = json_encode($array);
header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo $json;
```

and I'm getting this json response back

```
["http:\/\/i.ytimg.com\/sb\/V1NW91yW6MA\/storyboard3_L$L\/$N.jpg|48#27#100#10#10#0#default#u1jFfmylte0U7wBdj-0y3T8QUoE|80#45#62#10#10#2000#M$M#6UGOrQjHjUWAcarfFSbcRU_Gpkk|160#90#62#5#5#2000#M$M#hmCD_gj5t0-le7cm2xCBbkED6UI"]
```

I want to get a URL like this

```
http://i.ytimg.com/sb/V1NW91yW6MA/storyboard3_L1/M0.jpg?sigh=6UGOrQjHjUWAcarfFSbcRU_Gpkk
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code keeping you from getting the data you'd like:
- You shouldn't use `parse_str` on its own, as this can cause unexpected variable overwriting and other bad stuff.
- `parse_str` already does what you're trying with `explode`
- The `storyboard_spec` field contains information for all available pictures in a special format that needs to be parsed properly

Changing parts of you code to something like this should do the trick:

```
// Fetch the video meta data
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=V1NW91yW6MA&asv=3&el=detailpage&hl=en_US';
$data = file_get_contents($url);

// Extract the meta data to an array
$video_info = array();
parse_str($data, $video_info);

// Decode and split up the storyboard specs
$spec_parts = urldecode($video_info['storyboard_spec']);
$spec_parts = explode('|', $spec_parts);

// Extract and build the base URL
$base_url = explode('$', $spec_parts[0]);
$base_url = $base_url[0] . '2/M';

// Extract the sigh parameter
$sigh = explode('#', $spec_parts[3]);
$sigh = array_pop($sigh);

// Find the number of images
if($video_info['length_seconds'] >= 1200) {
    $count = $video_info['length_seconds'] / 240;
} else {
    $count = 5;
}

// Build the URL list
$urls = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i += 1){
    $urls[] = $base_url . $i . '.jpg?sigh=' . $sigh;
}

// Output the result as JSON
$json = json_encode($urls);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $json;
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply i'm face this problem with your coding Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in E:\xampp\xamp Installed\htdocs\apit\teststack.php on line 23

Comment: Sorry, should've been `>=` and not `=>`

Comment: a problem on line 23 `if($spec_parts['length_seconds'] => 1200) {`

Comment: Yeah, I updated the code above – that line should've been `if($spec_parts['length_seconds'] >= 1200) {`

Comment: dear this is real sigh `6UGOrQjHjUWAcarfFSbcRU_Gpkk` URL is not working and i'm facing still error on line 23

Comment: bro this is not real signature `hmCD_gj5t0-le7cm2xCBbkED6UI` this is real signature `6UGOrQjHjUWAcarfFSbcRU_Gpkk` in the center of URL

Comment: I found the other problem, and have just tested the code and everything (including the signature) seems to work just fine :)

Comment: Dear i found the problem Change the `$spec_parts[3]` with `$spec_parts[2]` and then change `'1/M'` with `'1/M'` and change count 5 to 1 and i want to get the answer likh this `{"story_board":"http:\/\/i.playit.pk\/sb\/G_0TziI12SE\/storyboard3_L1\/M0.jpg?sigh=wa1cIFpwGxMNbz9bRlRFZCkjlOc","length_seconds":"145"}`

Comment: and i want to replace URL `i.ytimg.com` to my domain name like as `i.example.com`

Comment: The output format should be easy for you to change, and it seems there are several pictures for a video so I'm not sure what you wanna do from here.  
But now I've shown you why your original code wasn't working and how to proceed :)

Comment: Dear bro your coding is fine Some pb but i handle please tell me only one Question i;m trying to add my `domain` and hide `i.ytimg.com `under my domain but when i try this code `/// Change URL 
$board_url = 'http://i.ytimg.com/sb/'.$id.'/storyboard3_L1/M0.jpg?sigh='.$sigh;
$actual_url = $board_url;
$get_result = str_replace('i.ytimg.com','example.com',$actual_url);` name replaced but did not work

Comment: That's good to hear :) to get your domain in, you could just put it in from the start, like this: `$board_url = 'http://'.$your_domain.'/sb/'.$id.'/storyboard3_L1/M0.jpg?sigh='.$sigh;`

Comment: dear i'm try this code for replace domain `$urls = $base_url.'.jpg?sigh=' . $sigh;
// Creat Custom URL
$replace_url = 'i.example.com';  /// Insert Your Domain Name 
$get_result = str_replace('i.ytimg.com',$replace_url,$urls);` URL replaced ok but when i paste the URL on address bar they are not work

Comment: Forwarding from your domain to another is a whole other business, but I'm glad you got it working so far :)

Comment: Thanks Dear i got the point and i find my way thanks bundle of thanks

Comment: As of now it seems that the calculation for the image amount (if video is longer than 20 minutes) is incorrect. Do you know the correct calculation?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to understand on what you're really after so I'll take a stab in the dark here. Is this what you're looking for?

- http://ctrlq.org/code/19236-youtube-storyboard-bookmarklet

Comment: i want to get storyboard in php with json respond

Comment: Ah I see! Here's a PHP wrapper of the YouTube Data API which would do this for you: https://github.com/madcoda/php-youtube-api. Or you can checkout the API directly: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php?hl=en

Comment: I believe Storyboards/extended thumbnails are not exposed by YouTube Data APIs, see https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=2946